# Converting Date to String (strftime) in one Line

Tags: python-3.x, datetime

There's a dictionary `data` with `Date`  as `key`.
I'd like to get the `max` Date from the Dictionary and convert it to a string with a slightly different form: `.` instead of `-` between `%Y-%m-%d` and changing the order of `%Y` and `%d`

This is how I did it:

```
date_maximal = max(datum for datum in data.keys())
date_maximal = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_maximal,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
date_maximal = date_maximal.strftime("%d.%m.%Y %H:%M")
```

Is there an option cram this into one line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
datetime.datetime.strptime(max(datum for datum in data.keys()), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M").strftime("%d.%m.%Y %H:%M")
```

This appears to be the quickest way to convert a date into a different format.